# Share pthread semaphore between processes

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm trying to create a shared semaphore class in C and share it between 2 processes via shared memory.

**SharedMemory.h** (Shared across processes)

```
typedef struct Semaphore {
    int value;              //- The semaphore's value
    int wakeups;            //- The number of pending signals to
                            //      avoid thread starvation
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;  //- Used to protect value and wakeups
    pthread_cond_t *cond;    //- For waiting on the semaphore
} Semaphore;

Semaphore *sem; //- Semaphore 1: Free | 0: In use
```

**SharedMemory.c** (Shared across processes)

```
//- Initialize Semaphore object
Semaphore *semaphore_init(int value)
{
    Semaphore *semaphore = (Semaphore*) malloc(sizeof(Semaphore));
    semaphore->value = value;
    semaphore->wakeups = 0;

    //- Mutex init
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attrmutex);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attrmutex, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    semaphore->mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    pthread_mutex_init(semaphore->mutex, &attrmutex);

    //- Condition init
    pthread_condattr_init(&attrcond);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&attrcond, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    semaphore->cond = (pthread_cond_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_cond_t));
    pthread_cond_init(semaphore->cond, &attrcond);

    return semaphore;
}

int signalSemaphore(Semaphore* sem)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(sem->mutex);
    /* TODO illustrative example: don't worry about overflow */
    sem->value++;
    pthread_cond_signal(sem->cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(sem->mutex);
    return 0;
}

//- Wait for semaphore
int waitSemaphore(Semaphore* sem)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(sem->mutex);

    while(sem->value == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(sem->cond, sem->mutex);
    }
    sem->value--;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(sem->mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

My server calls `sem = semaphore_init(1);`

**Theory 1**

Should my client call `semaphore_init` as well?

Or should it be a different function using `pthread_mutexattr_getshared` and `pthread_condattr_getshared`?

What's the best way to set this up?
Right now, when my client calls `waitSemaphore(sem)` it throws a segmentation fault.

Comment: There is very good example of custom semaphore implementation for PROCESS_SHARED type at http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_init. Refer to section "Process Shared Memory and Synchronization" on this page. May that help you.

Comment: Wow, I saw that page too, but obviously missed that section. Thanks a lot!!